# Username in urls for nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a new rails developer making an application where I have a user profile like: `localhost:3000/posts` routing to `localhost:3000/Charles` where Charles is the username.

So the code I'm using to do this looks like:

routes.rb

```
match "/:username" => "posts#index"
```

and then in my controller:

```
@user = User.find_by_username params[:username]
@search = Post.search do |query|
    query.fulltext params[:search]
    query.with(:user, @user.id)
end
```

this works great just for the post index, but I'd like to have posts/18 (for example) be routed to /username/posts/18.

So basically, I'm asking if there's a way to do something like this:

```
match "/:username" => "posts#index" do
  resources :posts
end
```

Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
scope ':username' do
  resources :posts
end
```

`bundle exec rake routes`

```
    posts GET    /:username/posts(.:format)          posts#index
          POST   /:username/posts(.:format)          posts#create
 new_post GET    /:username/posts/new(.:format)      posts#new
edit_post GET    /:username/posts/:id/edit(.:format) posts#edit
     post GET    /:username/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show
          PUT    /:username/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
          DELETE /:username/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#destroy
```

Comment: That will get you /posts/1/Charles, and /posts/Charles, he wants /Charles/posts/1

Answer (score 2):

This

```
  scope '/:username' do
    resources :posts
  end
```

produces what you want:

```
    posts GET    /:username/posts(.:format)          posts#index
          POST   /:username/posts(.:format)          posts#create
 new_post GET    /:username/posts/new(.:format)      posts#new
edit_post GET    /:username/posts/:id/edit(.:format) posts#edit
     post GET    /:username/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show
          PATCH  /:username/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
          PUT    /:username/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
          DELETE /:username/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#destroy
```

Answer (score 1):

```
match "/:username/posts/:id" => "posts#show"
```

But that won't really help when you need to edits and such.  So, try:

```
scope "/:username" do
  resources :posts
end
```

That failing:

```
scope "/:username" do
  get '' => "posts#index"
  get 'posts/:id' => "posts#show"
end
```

Hopefully the first will work.  Haven't tried it myself so forgive me, but I'm pretty sure that, in general, scope is what you want.